# ColdFusion 2018 Admin Console Shows Indestructible Search Bar

Tags: coldfusion, console, adobe

When I login to ColdFusion 2018 admin console the screenshot below shows up. The close button is not working. Neither is the search box. Restarting the WebLogic server and reopening console are not helpful. How to fix this? I never had this issue using ColdFusion console before this.

[image]

This is the console log in browser. No error reported in Eclipse.

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the ColdFusion log files?

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, put in a ticket with Adobe.

Comment: Issue fixed. Do upvote the question if you found it useful or as a reference in future. Special thanks to Edwin for helping me out the issue on Adobe Forums.

Comment: Please post link to issue on Adobe Forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be an incorrect value in your neo-runtime.xml file. CfFormScriptSrc value should be just "/cf_scripts/scripts/". For those who don't understand, refer to the discussion at https://forums.adobe.com/message/10705035

Comment: Yes it was me, the same guy here :D Thanks for the solution anyway.

Comment: @no0b3 Glad to be of help!

Comment: This also solved this problem for me. Just a couple notes in case they help anyone. 1) With me, the original value was just "/scripts1/". 2) I had to restart the CF service for the fix to take effect -- I should have known that but it took me a few minutes to realize it. Thank you immensely for this solution.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing the `/cf_scripts` mapping that serves the jQuery script that is required to run the frontend of the CF2018 admin console.

The mapping should point to `/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/wwwroot/cf_scripts/`.

If you are using the built-in Tomcat, locate `/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/runtime/conf/server.xml` and adjust your context:

```
<Context path="" docBase="/your-webroot/" workDir="/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/runtime/conf/Catalina/localhost/tmp">
    <Resources>
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/wwwroot/CFIDE" webAppMount="/CFIDE" />
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/wwwroot/WEB-INF" webAppMount="/WEB-INF" />
        <PreResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="/ColdFusion2018/cfusion/wwwroot/cf_scripts" webAppMount="/cf_scripts" />
    </Resources>
</Context>
```

If you are using IIS, you can simly add a virtual directory. A symlink would probably work too for that matter.

Comment: I never knew tht ColdFusion 2016 runs on jQuery UI jQuery UI 1.8.16 and jQuery 3.1.1

Comment: @JamesAMohler ColdFusion 2018 uses JQuery. 2016 would run without Jquery.